# Chat backup of my WhatsApp account#Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

I did WhatsApp chat backup to my Google Drive in the months of November 2019 but in the month of December my phone display has gone.

So when I am trying to install WhatsApp in new phone and get the chat history from Google Drive it's not detecting any backup from my Google Drive it's says no backup is found but I am sure I did backup of the complete chat history.

It's very important for me. I am not really getting how to get those backup in my new phone and recently, two days ago it's got exit from all the groups and deleted the profile pic, also I just want to know:

- Will my account be deleted now?
- How can I back those chats in my new phone?

Comment: Login to your [Google Drive](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=wise&passive=true&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2F%3Futm_source%3Den&utm_medium=button&utm_campaign=web&utm_content=gotodrive&usp=gtd&ltmpl=drive&urp=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin) and see if WhatsApp backup is there or not. If it is there login your phone with the Gmail address and then login to WhatsApp with the same phone number. See if it helps.

Comment: Hii Actually I did backup to Google drive in the month of November but when I tried to restore the messages from drive it was saying no backups found ...

Comment: And in my old phone WhatsApp database folder is there which is related to chats n backup So will it restore my messages ?if I install what's app in new phone ?I dint use whatsapp for 2 months so my WhatsApp account has been deleted automatically Soo jus want to know as it's very important to me to get those chats kindly help me to get this thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Will my account be deleted now?
```

No

Try checking if the same google account you have(on which you have took the backup) if no, add that google account on your phone, if yes this might help you
https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/chats/how-to-restore-your-chat-history/?lang=en